# Java Parsing Using Hmap

Tags: java, parsing, split

I am new to Java. I want to Parse the data which is in this Format

Apple;Mango;Orange:1234;Orange:1244;...;

There could be more than one "Orange" at any point of time. Numbers (1,2...) increase and accordingly as the "Orange".

Okay. After splitting it, Lets assume I have stored the first two data(Apple, Orange) in  a variable(in setter) to return the same in the getter function. And now I want to add the value(1234,1244....etc) in the 'orange' thing into a variable to return it later. Before that i have to check how many oranges have come. For that, i know i have to use for loop. But don't know how to store the "Value" into a variable.

Please Help me guys.

Comment: Which value into which variable? I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

```
 String input = "Apple;Mango;Orange:1234;Orange:1244;...;"
 String values[] = input.split(";");
 String value1 = values[0];
 String value2 = values[1];

 Hashmap< String, ArrayList<String> > map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
 for(int i = 2; i < values.length; i = i + 2){
      String key = values[i];
      String id = values[i+1];

      if (map.get(key) == null){
          map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
      }
      map.get(key).add(id);
 }

 //for any key s:
  // get the values of s
  map.get(s);  // returns a list of all values added
  // get the count of s
  map.get(s).size(); // return the total number of values.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to rephrase the question by how I interpreted it and -- more importantly -- how it focuses on the input and output (expectations), not the actual implementation:

> I need to parse the string
>
> `"Apple;Mango;Orange:1234;Orange:1244;...;"`
>
> in a way so I can retrieve the values associated (numbers after `':'`) with the fruits:
>
> - I should receive an empty list for both the *Apple* and *Mango* in the example, because they have no value;
> - I should receive a list of `1234, 1244` for *Orange*.

Of course your intuition of `HashMap` is right on the spot, but someone may always present a better solution if you don't get too involved with the specifics.

There are a few white spots left:

- Should the fruits without values have a default value given?
- Should the fruits without values be in the map at all?
- How input errors should be handled?
- How duplicate values should be handled?

---

Given this context, we can start writing code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FruitMarker {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Apple;Mango;Orange:1234;Orange:1244";
    // replace with parameter processing from 'args'

    // avoid direct implementations in variable definitions
    // also observe the naming referring to the function of the variable
    Map<String, Collection<Integer>> fruitIds = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();

    // iterate through items by splitting
    for (String item : input.split(";")) {
      String[] fruitAndId = item.split(":"); // this will return the same item in an array, if separator is not found
      String fruitName = fruitAndId[0];
      boolean hasValue = fruitAndId.length > 1;

      Collection<Integer> values = fruitIds.get(fruitName);
      // if we are accessing the key for the first time, we have to set its value
      if (values == null) {
        values = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // here I can use concrete implementation
        fruitIds.put(fruitName, values);   // be sure to put it back in the map
      }
      if (hasValue) {
        int fruitValue = Integer.parseInt(fruitAndId[1]);
        values.add(fruitValue);
      }
    }

    // display the entries in table iteratively
    for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> entry : fruitIds.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
    }
  }

}
```

If you execute this code, you will get the following output:

```
Mango => []
Apple => []
Orange => [1234, 1244]
```